# Does Logic 9 solve the lost MIDI mapping problems that were present in Logic 8?

Tags: midi, logic-pro, setup

This is a follow up to [this question I asked months ago](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/256/why-does-logic-8-lose-the-daw-controller-mappings-from-my-m-audio-axiom-49-betwee). My MIDI mappings are still being lost even if I keep the Axiom turned on between sessions in Logic and it's maddening. It's a lot of work to rebuild them every session.

[Apparently this is a known issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2402208?threadID=2402208). The solutions in that Apple Support thread don't work for me. Restoring the .cs file between sessions doesn't stop the mappings from disappearing completely.

I'd upgrade to Logic 9 if I knew the money spent would buy me a solution to this problem. Can anyone confirm or deny that this issue is gone in Logic 9 when you're using an M-Audio Axiom (generation 1) controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case: yes. The upgrade seems to have solved the problem. At least, I've gone two days now (and many project open/close cycles) without the mappings disappearing. That's not something I was ever able to do with Logic 8.